# Which buttons does hasPermanentMenuKey() check in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey%28%29) mentions "a menu key" but then what does it refer to exactly? Is it only the one that shows the options menu or does it refer to the "Home" button, "Recent" button etc. In other words, does `hasPermanentMenuKey()` mean to check whether a device has physical/ hardware buttons i.e. just any combinations of "Home", "Recent", "Search" etc.?

If the "menu key" mentioned in Android documentation really means the options menu button, how can we know that having physical options menu button = having physical buttonS for all devices out there?

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the hardware "Menu" button usually found as the right button in the following device:
[image]

As you can see in the documentation of this method here [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey%28%29) this method reports if the device has a permanent menu key available to the user.